# Angular Material "md-chips" directive how to control that input field on select was focused not chip container?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

Angular Material "md-chips" directive how to control that input field on select was focused not chip container?

Chip template:

```
<md-chips name="limits" md-autocomplete-snap=""
          ng-model="ctrl.selectedVegetables"
          md-transform-chip="ctrl.transformChip($chip)"
          md-require-match="ctrl.autocompleteDemoRequireMatch" 
          md-enable-chip-edit="true"              
          >

  <md-autocomplete md-min-length="0"
                   md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" 
                   md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.name" 
                   placeholder="Search for a vegetable" md-no-cache="true">
      <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.name}}</span>
  </md-autocomplete>     

  <md-chip-template>

    <label>{{$chip.name}}</label>      
    <input required type="number" ng-model="$chip.change" step="0.01"/>
    <md-icon style="margin-top: -6px"> %</md-icon>

  </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

There is working example: 
[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/Drasius/pen/KaBOPG)

How to make that when chip is selected  the input field is focused but not chip container it self. Try to edit number value and you will understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution:

1- Add an id for the input you want to be focused, to be unique I'll set this id to be `chip.$$hashkey`:

`<input type="number" step="0.01" required ng-model="$chip.change" ng-attr-id="{{$chip.$$hashKey}}" style="padding-left: 3px; margin-left: 3px" />`

2- In the select event handler, you force the focus:

`self.selectChip = (data) => {
    if(data)
        document.getElementById(data.$$hashKey).focus();
}`